# bash replace one character from the end of string

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace

I need to replace last dot to character '-' in the string.

```
# a='2.5.2.pl'
```

Using the following expression:

```
# echo ${a/%./-}
```

I expect to get:

```
2.5.2-pl
```

but i get

```
2.5.2.pl
```

I noticed that it doesn't work only if I need to replace the dot from the end to the beginning. Why does it happen?
Of course I can use external programs like awk, sed to solve this problem but I need to solve the problem using only bash.

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With bash‘s [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
a='2.5.2.pl'
echo "${a%.*}-${a##*.}"
```

Output:

```
2.5.2-pl
```

Answer (score 0):

My way is a bit hacky and uses `rev` but I tested it and it works!

```
echo "$(_b=$(echo "$a" | rev); _b=${_b/./-}; echo "$_b" | rev)"
```

Basically, I just reversed the character order so the last `.` was first and then used `${var/./-}` to replace the dot with a dash and finally reversed the order of the characters again.

Comment: There's quite a set of bugs here. Try having whitespace-surrounded wildcards, tab characters, or other oddness in your strings -- and see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo). (The ease of having something *look* like it works, while having bugs when executed with even slightly-different data, is part of why it's important to understand the execution model for bash, rather than accepting a successful test to have meaning besides the specific inputs and domain where that test took place).

Comment: I don't see that being a problem with what the OP asked.

Comment: Code gets reused outside its initial domain. Robust practices are safely reusable; fragile practices... aren't. And reuse isn't always intentional, either -- the worst data loss event I was present for happened when someone was sloppy in quoting in a shell script because it "could only ever" run in a directory containing names matching `[0-9a-f]{24}` -- then a bug in a separate program created a filename with garbage dumped from memory, and the script expanded a glob in that name and deleted TB of billing data backups.

Comment: Anyhow, part of the point of StackOverflow is that we're creating a teaching resource -- it's a reasonable expectation that code given in a teaching resource is going to be *correct*, not full of hidden pitfalls and caveats.

Comment: Okay, I'll update it to something that should work outside of it's initial domain.